# When I add in Java transformationMatrix I can't see images?

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es

When I add in Java transformationMatrix I can't see images moving but when I remove it I can see why and how to fix it? Any ideas how to fix it?

My Renderer class:

```
public class Renderer {

    private static final float FOV = 70;
    private static final float NEAR_PLANE = 0.1f;
    private static final float FAR_PLANE = 1000;

    private Matrix4f projectionMatrix;

    public Renderer(StaticShader shader){
        createProjectionMatrix();
        shader.start();
        shader.loadProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);
        shader.stop();
    }

    public void prepare(){
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    public void render(Entity entity,StaticShader shader){
        TexturedModel model = entity.getModel();
        RawModel rawModel = model.getRawModel();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(rawModel.getVaoID());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        Matrix4f transformationMatrix = Maths.createTransformationMatrix(entity.getPosition(), entity.getRotX(), entity.getRotY(), entity.getRotZ(), entity.getScale());
        shader.loadTransformationMatrix(transformationMatrix);
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, model.getTexture().getID());
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, rawModel.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    private void createProjectionMatrix(){
        float aspectRatio = (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight();
        float y_scale = (float) ((1f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV / 2f))) * aspectRatio);
        float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;
        float frustum_length = FAR_PLANE - NEAR_PLANE;

        projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        projectionMatrix.m00 = x_scale;
        projectionMatrix.m11 = y_scale;
        projectionMatrix.m22 = -((FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
        projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
        projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * NEAR_PLANE * FAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
        projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;
    }

}
```

Edit aded StaticShader class:
`package shader;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Matrix4f;

public class StaticShader extends ShaderProgram{

```
private static final String VERTEX_FILE = "src/shader/vertexShader.txt";
private static final String FRAGMENT_FILE = "src/shader/fragmentShader.txt";

private int location_transformationMatrix;
private int location_projectionMatrix;

public StaticShader() {
    super(VERTEX_FILE, FRAGMENT_FILE);
}

@Override
protected void bindAttributes() {
    super.bindAttribute(0, "position");
    super.bindAttribute(1, "textureCoords");
}

@Override
protected void getAllUniformLocations() {
    location_transformationMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("transformationMatrix");
    location_projectionMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("projectionMatrix");
}

public void loadTransformationMatrix(Matrix4f matrix){
    super.loadMatrix(location_transformationMatrix, matrix);
}

public void loadProjectionMatrix(Matrix4f projection){
    super.loadMatrix(location_projectionMatrix, projection);
}
```

}
`
Edit vertexShader.txt

`#version 400 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec3 colour;
out vec2 pass_textureCoords;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main(void){

```
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
colour = vec3(position.x+0.5,0.0,position.y+0.5);
```

}`

Comment: ohh i got my entity.getScale() is 1.0

Comment: i see changing coordinates but i dont see images on the screen?

Comment: i add StaticShader class for you

Comment: i can't see my modules then how to fix the camera?

Comment: i add vertexShader.txt for you